# Javascript validate that provided number is in increments of 50

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate in Javascript that a number is in increments of 50, if not, then throw a validation error. For example:

- 123 - invalid, can either be 100 or 150
- 272 - invalid, can either be 200 or 250 or 300

etc...

I'm thinking that the `%` remainder operator is what I need to use but not quite sure how to build a javascript validation rule to match this.

Comment: `if (input % 50) { /* handle invalid input */ }`

Comment: `123 % 50` would result in `23` whereas `100 % 50` results in `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
(val) => {
    var remainder = val % 50;
    if (remainder !== 0) {
        var lower = val - remainder;
        var higher = lower + 50;
        throw new Error(val + ' - invalid, can either be ' + String(lower) + ' or ' + String(higher));
    }
}
```

That could be reduced, but this way you can see the logic at work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the math you want to preform:

```
Math.round(123/ 50)*50; //this gives 100 
Math.ceil(123/ 50)*50; //this gives 150
```

and here is the validation function

```
function validate(number) {
  var round = Math.round(number / 50) * 50; 
  var ceil = Math.ceil(number / 50) * 50; 

  if (number == round) { return console.log("valid"); }
  return console.log(`${number} - invali, can eiher be ${round} or ${ceil}`);
}
```